# Regular expression to accept only a few alphabetic characters

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel

I am developing a Laravel application. I want to write a custom regex rule that accepts only few alphabets such as `a,j,k` (not all three mandatory)? I am stuck with `^[a-zA-Z]+$`. But this accepts all alphabetic characters. Any idea?

Comment: explain in detail with example

Comment: simple, question....

Comment: @AvinashRaj Not a simple question for regex beginner. And your answer will not work. It makes all 3 alphabets as required.

Comment: see the title, regex to accept only few alphabets..

Comment: @Corner did you test it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes the title is correct. But I didn't mention that all 3 alphabets are mandatory. User can only enter any these 3 alphabets.

Comment: @Clayton yes. It works, but only if I enter all 3 alphabets.

Comment: in your post you say they are not all mandatory now you are saying they are all mandatory... which one do you mean, what you say is confusing.

Comment: @Clayton Oops! Did I mention that all fields are mandatory? I don't know. Actually all alphabets are not mandatory. But accepts only these 3

Comment: please post your code, we need a lot more context to understand you

Comment: Are you looking for a regex that allows an empty string match? Use `*` instead of `+`: [`^[ajk]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/vA3tI2/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[ajk]+
```

And I suggest you this webpage

**https://regex101.com/**